# Edit all aspects of an existing ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am building a web app where a user can select various datasets and plot them. Currently the plotting and visualization is done in R using ggplot2.

What is the most generic / flexible way to edit an existing ggplot?

Some use cases / examples below:

1. Change from bar chart to points

[image]
[image]

2. Add a linear regression to a user defined dataset
   [image]
   [image]

Comment: You might find some inspiration in the [esquisse](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/esquisse/readme/README.html) package

Comment: I'm not sure I know what you mean specifically by "edit an existing ggplot." I find it difficult to edit a ggplot object after it is created, e.g. using `ggplot2::ggplot_build`, but it's relatively easy to make a shiny app show different charts based on user input, e.g. https://mastering-shiny.org/basic-case-study.html#rate-vs-count